# Can we connect Azure Blob with QnA maker knowledge base?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-qna-maker

Can someone tell me if we can connect Azure Blob with QnA maker knowledge base?

Answer (score 0):

QnA Maker now is known as Question Answering under Azure Language Service. Based on the document, there is no need to connect blob with your service since both the export and import are as csv/excel format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/export-import-refresh#export-a-project

If you are in different scenario, please share to us so we can forward it to product team.